# Failed to resolve--compile 'com.android.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'

Tags: android, firebase

I am facing this error:

**[Failed to resolve--compile 'com.android.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELTku.gif)**

**Here is the app gradle file:**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kartik.barcode"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'

compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'//for The edittext animation

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'//for firebase

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'

compile 'com.android.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

[Here is the **SDK Tool Tab**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELTku.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
compile 'com.android.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
```